# How to access Firebird system tables through SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, firebird

I want to use automap to get database schema and start working with system tables (like MON$ RDB$) as objects.

like

```py
    Base = automap_base()
    Base.prepare(
        autoload_with=engine
    )

    Session().query(Base.classes.mon.Statements).all()
```

[image]